# How to add border in pandas dataframe to html table row header?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pandas

Pandas style options let me format the data but i want to add border to the column headers, that is row 0.

```
htmlFooterOutdatedList = dfServerOutdated[['System Name','IP Address','Last Communication','DAT (VSE)','OS Type','Status']].style.hide_index().set_properties(**{'font-size': '10pt','background-color': '#edeeef','border-color': 'black','border-style' :'solid' ,'border-width': '1px','border-collapse':'collapse', 'padding': '5px'}).applymap(datversion,subset = 'DAT (VSE)').applymap(LTSCDate,subset = 'Last Communication').background_gradient(cmap='PuBu', low=0, high=0, axis=0, subset='DAT (VSE)', text_color_threshold=0.458).set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th', 'props': [('font-size', '12pt')]}]).set_properties(subset=['Last Communication'], **{'width': '180px'}).set_properties(subset=['System Name'], **{'width': '30px'}).set_properties(subset=['Status'], **{'width': '90px'}).render()
```

[image: Whi the rows are formatted, the column header border is missing which I want to add.]

Can I add borders to column headers ?

Answer (score 10):

Inside your (admittedly very long) line of code, you already have:

```
.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th', 'props': [('font-size', '12pt')]}])
```

which you can expand by common CSS attributes, e.g.:

```
.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th', 'props': [('font-size', '12pt'),('border-style','solid'),('border-width','1px')]}])
```